# Find range of the function $\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)^2$

Tags: functions

I came across the problem of finding range of the function,
$$f(x) = \left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)^2$$

I proceed as follow:
$$y = \left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)^2 $$
$$As, \left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)^2 \ge 0$$
$$So, y \ge 0$$
Hence, range of the given function is $\left[0,\infty\right).$

I know the answer is correct, but I am not sure about the process. Is this the correct way to do this ? If not, How to solve this problem ? I couldn't solve this by other methods.

Comment: An alternative to Kavi Rama Murthy's approach would be if you know or can prove that $(1 - \sqrt{x})^2$ is a continuous function that goes to $\infty$ as $x$ goes to $\infty.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt x=1\pm \sqrt y\ge 0\implies \pm \sqrt y\ge -1$

Noting that $y\ge 0$, we have two cases:

**Case 1:** $\sqrt y\ge -1$
This is true for all $y\in [0,\infty)$
**Case 2:** $ -\sqrt y\ge -1\implies \sqrt y\le 1\implies 0\le y\le 1\implies y\in [0,1]$ 
Therefore the range is $[0,1]\cup [0,\infty)=[0,\infty)$

Answer (score 6):

You proved that the range is contained in $[0,\infty)$ not that it is equal to $[0,\infty)$. You have to take any $y$ in this interval and show that $y$ is actually in the range. For this you have to solve the equation $(1-\sqrt x)^{2}=y$. Can you do that?

Comment: I couldn't solve that equation to find range.

Comment: In case you wish to disagree, see the comment following the query that I just left

Comment: $x=(1+\sqrt y)^{2}$ is a solution. @RohitJoshi

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x = \left(1\pm\sqrt{y}\right)^2$ ?

Comment: @RohitJoshi Yes, but for this question it is enough to find one value of $x$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: Can you show me how to deduce the result after this expression ?

Comment: @RohitJoshi Once you find $x$ such that $f(x)=y$ (for any $y\in [0,\infty)$) you are done. By definition of range that would prove that the range of $f$ is $[0,\infty)$

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. The way this answer has been worded/paraphrased is truly fantastic. "You proved that the range is contained in $[0,\infty)$ not that it is equal to ...". Amazing! :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach to completing the problem.

To show: 
$f(x) = (1 - \sqrt{x})^2$ is surjective on $[0,\infty)$ as $x$ goes from $1$ to $\infty$.

$\sqrt{x}$ is known to be a continuous strictly increasing function.  Therefore, so is $f(x)$.

Further since $\sqrt{x} \to \infty$ as $x\to \infty, f(x)$ is unbounded, as $x \to \infty.$

Suppose there exists $r \in \Bbb{R^+}$ such that $r$ is not in the range of $f$.  Since $f$ is unbounded, choose $s$ such that $f(s) > r.$

Consider the closed interval $[1,s]$.  By the intermediate value theorem, $f$, being continuous, takes on every value between $f(1)$ and $f(s)$.  Therefore, since $0 < r < f(s)$, there must be some value $t$ in $[1,s]$ such that $f(t) = r.$

This yields a contradiction.  Therefore, it can not be the case that there exists any $r \in \Bbb{R^+}$ that is outside the range of $f$.

Comment: Beautiful Proof. Sadly couldn't accept mutiple answers. But thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you proved nothing because you directly stated the answer

$$(1-\sqrt x)^2\ge0.$$

This is a true statement, but you did not verify if all non-negative values can be reached. A more complete discussion is

$$x\ge0\implies1-\sqrt x\in[-\infty,1)=(0,1]\cup(-\infty,0]\implies(1-\sqrt x)^2\ge0$$ and the inequalities are tight.

Comment: Any justification for this downvote ?

Comment: Do you disagree with the comment that I left, following the query?  No idea who downvoted you.\

Comment: @user2661923: no, this is not enough.

Comment: Interesting, I thought that the Intermediate value theorem would kick in.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But range of $1-\sqrt x$ is $1$ to $-\infty$.

Comment: @Eisenstein: yep, my bad, thanks for pointing that.

Comment: @user2661923: depends on the "depth" of the proof. You can take for granted that if $x$ covers all positives, so does $x^2$, or not.

Comment: actually, I was simply assuming that $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous and increases without bound.